# Did Poe Dameron make custom modifications to his black X-Wing?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, poe-dameron

In Star Wars: The Force Awakens and The Last Jedi, it is obvious that Poe Dameron is the coolest X-Wing pilot to have ever existed. He an extremely skilled pilot, but I have a head canon that he has made custom modifications and tweaks that even the Resistance doesn't know about, such as removing inertial dampeners or other modifications, which help his fighter out-perform other X-Wings.

So even if Poe were to fly another X-Wing, he would not be able to fly as well.

***Except for the super booster at the beginning of The Last Jedi, is there any canon evidence to support the theory that Poe Dameron's black X-Wing has special modifications which allow it to out-perform the other X-Wings in the fleet?***

Comment: Out-perform, not that I can see. It has a custom black paintjob that allows it to evade enemy sensors.

Comment: In the novels, at least, the inertial damper was user-configurable, so it wouldn't have to be modified as such.

Comment: and *removing* it will likely result in a very, **very** squishy, pulped, dead pilot, given the acceleration Star Wars spaceships are seen to do.

Comment: "It is obvious Poe Dameron is the coolest X-Wing pilot to have ever existed." ...Not obvious to me at all.

Comment: Not able to fly others as well because he'd be too busy mansplaining about how cool his black one was. "extremely skilled pilot" ? Does anyone ever say that in the movie? IMO there's no on-screen evidence of that. Not that it really matters; this question needs nothing but its title so +1.

Comment: "it is obvious that Poe Dameron is the coolest X-Wing pilot to have ever existed" Amazing, every word of what you just said was wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're damn right he does. Poe is extremely proud of his customised X-Wing and likes to keep the flight systems *just the way he likes them* as this maintenance report (from [Poe Dameron: Flight Log](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Poe_Dameron:_Flight_Log)) shows.

In brief, he likes the thrusters and electromagnetic gyroscopes to be calibrated to his own personal specifications and he likes the flight controls "oiled" and "loose".

[image]

Comment: #2 on that list is just about exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't know this book existed.

Comment: @Newbie12345 - [Gotta catch 'em all ;-)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Black_One#Sources)

Comment: ...He actually wrote "bigger, badder ships" in an official report...?

Comment: @jpmc26 - Like most fighter pilots, Poe is 98% ego, 2% ego.

Comment: None of that really sounds like any invasive modification, just some preferences regarding maintenance and calibration. Reading this it seems like his X-wing is still a regular stock model.

Comment: I agree with @Philipp but this definitely answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In the *Last Jedi* novelization, there's a section from BB-8's point of view describing Poe's ship, *Black One*, as uniquely difficult to work with:

> Behind Poe in the starfighter's droid socket, BB-8 was already dealing with a lengthy list of mostly irrelevant alerts from the X-wing's central computer. That was nothing new: Every astromech in the Resistance droid pool could tell you that *Black One* was a prickly, vainglorious machine.
>
> [...]
>
> The Resistance astromechs classified *Black One* as a high-communications-volume interface. BB-8 searched his memory for an organic equivalent of that classification, and found a high-confidence answer almost immediately.
>
> *Black One* was a pain in the ass.
>
> *(Chapter 4, page 40 of Kindle edition)*

However, there's no mention of any physical modifications to the ship, besides the rocket booster on the back.

Comment: ... and just like that, I've realised the ship is "Black 1", not "the black one".